# Set the topic of a spring cloud stream kafka on runtime

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring cloud stream. I now how to create a static bindings using the application.yaml with Kafka. I would like to create a new one in the java code or modify the topic of a binding defined in the application.yaml. For example

```
cloud:
stream:
  default-binder: kafka
  function:
    definition: listenEnrichment
  bindings:
    listenEnrichment-in-0:
      destination: input
```

I would like to change destination input to other topic during runtime. Is it this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible nor intended to.
However, what we do have and what I believe you're really asking is for dynamic destination resolution. For that we have a component that you can inject called `StreamBridge` which you can use to send to arbitrary destinations. For example,

```
streamBridge.send("myDestination", "hello world");
```

You can get more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources)

That is for output, but for input we don't support it and never really intended to or been asked to, so I am wondering what is the actual business use case that makes you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I want to use it to verify / test a µservice, but after thinking about it, I solved it without this stuff.